# Different backend and frontend language files in a Joomla Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, language

this is my first post on stackoverflow. I apologize for my poor english. I developed a very complex joomla 3+ module with plenty of backend options. Labels and long description for every option is stored in the language file (more then 600 rows...). My problem is that module frontend only needs to load a few of this line (20 more or less) and I would not load all the others, which instead appear to be loaded anyway. It all gets worse because of repeated use of the module on the frontend, which causes, i guess, unecessary delays. I know plugins and components can manage different front and backend language files, but it is not possible for modules.

I wonder if can load language strings only for backend or better have totally different files for module front and backend

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I can't think of a way to achieve this at the moment. It might be possible though. But are you sure that the language files are responsible for the slow loading of your module?

Answer (score 2):

It is not feasible to load different set of strings, in backend and frontend, which are contained in a single file.

You should create multiple language files for this purpose.
Joomla support the concept of different language file for admin section and frontend.

Refer this [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files) for more details